# can an nhibernate transaction flush only changes committed to session?

Tags: c#, session, nhibernate, transactions, flush

Let's say I open an ISession from the SessionFactory.

For some limited time (not long) this session is alive and used.
I fetch entities from the database using this session, and change some of the entities according to some complex business rules.
Then I want to save only *some* of the changed entities.

So, naturally:

```
        ITransaction t = null;

        try
        {
            t = session.BeginTransaction();

            session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);

            t.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Logger.Error("Transaction failed.", ex);

            if (t != null)
                t.Rollback();

            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (t != null)
                t.Dispose();
        }
```

However, in accordance with the NH documentation, when transaction commit is called, the session is flushed. This means that **all** the *dirty* entities are persisted, even those which I didn't pass to SaveOrUpdate. If some are not in a valid state (e.g. no longer have their *not null* fk set) everything blows up completely - even if the entities which I tried to save are valid.

Is there a way to tell NH to only save the entity that I give it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `ISession.Evict` to remove objects from the session. My memory is that this affects only the object passed as the argument, not the entire object's graph, so changes to child collections are not evicted.

My suspicion is that your unit-of-work is too long. It's unusual to make changes to an entity that you do not want persisted to the database.

Oh, and the SaveOrUpdate call is unnecessary.

Comment: The nh docs should have a screaming red sign which says - think of a session as a transaction. I will solve this in some other way, but can you please add to your answer, what is the difference between the ISession and ITransaction?

Comment: I agree that the documentation should start with NHibernate's philosophy. It's confusing, especially since there's an Update method. This section describes behavior: http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#manipulatingdata.

Comment: A session is a unit of work and a transaction is a set of operations that should all succeed (commit) or fail (rollback) together. In almost all cases, one transaction per session is the best approach. If you use identity (autonumber) identifiers then NHibernate may save those changes at an unexpected time outside of a transaction. Lazy loading may also cause a read outside of a transaction. Profiling is essential when working with any ORM.

Comment: Somehow I have managed to read that doc many times without actually realizing that this problem of mine is the expected behavior :) In any case, so, a session can live longer than a transaction, if all goes well + adds lazy load:) Thank you for your answer. My 2c is that it would be great if NH had a FlushMode.MarkedOnly - which would then flush only those dirty entities (entity trees) which are explicitly marked (by calling some method not called SaveOrUpdate(..)). It would offer something extra to those who want it and not disturb the philosophy. What do you think? Should I create a fork? :)

Comment: why do *all* the changes have to be persisted? it would be good to have the option not to.. but i will not say there exists a broken abstraction in the session.

Comment: You do have the option to Evict from the session or Clear-ing the entire session. NHibernate assumes that changes will be persisted; Entity Framework requires an explicit save. It took some getting used to, but I prefer NHibernate's strategy. I think it really shines in web applications with short units-of-work.

Comment: Not sure those two would help me. In any case - one option more is better than one option less. And I would not consider the FlushMode.MarkedOnly bloat :) I rare use case - yes.. But one which could grow, develop and gain popularity :)

Comment: Because .. the entity is supposed to be persistence ignorant. If I can't change it arbitrarily without this disturbing my ability to persist some other entity - is the entity truly persistence ignorant?